# append rows to armadillo .mat file

Tags: c++, save, armadillo

Is there a way to append rows to a .mat file saved using the .save() function?

for example in the following for loop:

```
mat M; M.ones(1,5);

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        mat tmp;
        tmp = M + i;
        tmp.save("file.mat", arma_ascii) // + some code to append rather than overwrite;
    }
```

The idea being that I can avoid storing the data as a large matrix in my workspace.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can append rows/columns from `mat` using `.insert_rows()`, `.insert_cols()` methods. See [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#insert).

Answer (score 0):

The save() function only overwrites files. You can append to a text file, by, say using a row vector with the same number of columns using this code:

```
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("file.mat", std::ios::app);
    outfile << myRowVector;
    oufile.close();
```

The new line character is added automatically. The std::ios::app is used to append to files.